# why string array is not printing the output in C programming

Tags: arrays, c, string

I wrote this code in visual studio to print a statement based on entered cgpa marks but it's not printing the output, can I know what is the reason?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    float cgpa;
    char status[50];
    printf("Enter your cgpa: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &cgpa);
    if (cgpa > 3.0)
    {
        status[50] = "Second Upper Class ";
        if (cgpa > 3.75)
            status[50] = "First Class Degree";
    }
    else
    {
        if (cgpa > 2.0)
            status[50] = "Second Lower Class ";
        else
            status[50] = "Yet to complete ";
    }
    fputs(status,sizeof(status), stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

I edited the code with using `strcpy`, replacing `fputs` with `printf` and added `#pragma warning(disable: 4996)` for visual studio warnings of not using `strcpy_s`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma warning(disable: 4996)      
int main()
{
    float cgpa;
    char status[50] = { '\0' }, first[50] = { "First Class Degree" }, second[50] = { "Second Upper Class " }, third[50] = { "Second Lower Class " }, forth[50] = { "Yet to complete " };
    printf("Enter your cgpa: ");
    scanf_s("%f", &cgpa);
    if (cgpa > 3.0)
    {
        strcpy(status, second);
        if (cgpa > 3.75)
            strcpy(status, first);
    }

    else
    {
        if (cgpa > 2.0)
            strcpy(status, third);
        else
            strcpy(status, forth);
    }
    printf("%s", status);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What do you think `status[50] = "..."` does?

Comment: `status[50] = "Whatever";` is wrong in a lot of ways. Use something like `strcpy` instead.

Comment: Also, [`fputs`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fputs.3p.html) only takes 2 arguments: string and file stream. Your compiler should be giving an error for passing too many arguments.

Comment: Start with reading and fixing the warning you are most certainly getting.

Comment: Alright thanks everyone I fixed my code, you can check the question I edited it.

Comment: If allowed, use the [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compiler as `gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` then the [GDB](https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/) debugger. In all cases, take several hours to read the documentation of your C compiler and of your debugger

Comment: You need to flush the output stream.  Use `fflush(stdout)` after your printf's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did a quick review and added some very minor modifications.

There is never any guarantee that printf() will show output immediately.  The console is not necessarily displaying in "raw" mode, so you need to give it a good kick.

You can use `fflush(stdout)` to force flushing of stdout.  Also, appending '\n' to your printf's character string will usually do the trick.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> /* you need this for strcpy */

int main()
{
    float cgpa;
    char status[50] = { '\0' }, 
         first[50] = { "First Class Degree" }, 
         second[50] = { "Second Upper Class " }, 
         third[50] = { "Second Lower Class " }, 
         forth[50] = { "Yet to complete " };
    printf("Enter your cgpa: ");

    fflush(stdout); /* Ensure the question is displayed */

    scanf("%f", &cgpa); /* I used straight scanf() just for the test */
    if (cgpa > 3.0)
    {
        strcpy(status, second);
        if (cgpa > 3.75)
            strcpy(status, first);
    }

    else
    {
        if (cgpa > 2.0)
            strcpy(status, third);
        else
            strcpy(status, forth);
    }
    printf("\n%s\n", status); /* added '\n' for clearer output */

    fflush(stdout);

    return 0;
}
```